# error is " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0 " and the code is:

Tags: java, selenium

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class Web_driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_radio_button.cfm");
        List<WebElement> radio_button = driver.findElements(By.name("Preferred_color"));
        System.out.println(radio_button.get(1).getAttribute("value"));
```

after executing above code error is displayed "Exception in thread "main"

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at Web_driver.main(Web_driver.java:16)
```

Comment: If you change it to `findElement` you'll get ElementNotFoundException. Refine your locator firstly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not able to find the radio button with name "Preferred_color" and hence the returned list `radio_button` seems to be null. And hence when you try to call `radio_button.get(1)`, this causes `NullPointerException`

Add this null check to avoid exception:

```
    List<WebElement> radio_button = driver.findElements(By.name("Preferred_color"));
    if(radio_button !=null )
       System.out.println(radio_button.get(1).getAttribute("value"));
```

Comment: I have added the if(radio_button != null) line but still i am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

It finds no element with the given name on the web-page, the radio_button list is empty. Trying to fetch the first element gives an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Check the By.name to see how to find the elements. Also, in Java radio_button should be radioButton.

Answer (score 0):

It seams as if the statement:

```
driver.findElements(By.name("Preferred_color"));
```

does return an empty `List`. Check if the page you are at does define an element with name `Preferred_color`.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(radio_button.get(1).getAttribute("value"));
in this line you are trying to fetch the value from the empty thats the reason for the exception